# How can I make Electron channels more type safe?

Tags: typescript, electron

Here is how I handle communication over Electron channels:

`preload.ts`

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("myIpcRenderer", {
  invoke: (channel: Channel, ...args: any[]) =>
    callIpcRenderer("invoke", channel, ...args),
  send: (channel: Channel, ...args: any[]) =>
    callIpcRenderer("send", channel, ...args),
  on: (channel: Channel, ...args: any[]) =>
    callIpcRenderer("on", channel, ...args),
});
```

`types.d.ts`

```
interface MyIpcRenderer {
  invoke(channel: Channel.ReadFiles, ...args: any[]): Promise<ReadFileResult[]>;
}
```

The `MyIpcRenderer` type enforce correct use in `renderer.ts`:

```
const files = await window.myIpcRenderer.invoke(Channel.ReadFiles, [
  svgPath,
]);
```

But it does not enforce correct use in `main.ts`. `ipcMain.handle` refers to an electron method that can accept channels with any name and retturn any kind of promise.

```
ipcMain.handle(
  "anychannelnamegoes",
  async (_event, paths: string[]): Promise<any> => {
    ...
  }
);
```

How can I rewrite my code to enforce main usage in `main.ts` as well?

Comment: is there a reason you are not happy with good old JS variables instead of string literals `export const channelNames = {myIpcRenderer: 'myIpcRenderer'}`? (why do you need TS for this, what happened?)

Comment: @Aprillion: I'm not sure I understand your question. Let me know if you are asking for something else. The reason why I am using a TypeScript enum is that the entire project is written in TypeScript. I could use a JS object to achieve the same thing, but I think that would be less TypeScript ideomatic.

Comment: what I wanted to ask is why limiting the channel names by using variables like `ipcMain.handle(channelNames.myIpcRenderer, ...` is not sufficient? that is idiomatic TS, not just JS, when you want to choose from a limited set of values.. idiomatic TS for enforcing the limited set of values might look like `ipcMain.handle<SomeType>(...)` but that is up to the library authors to implement, not sure what you can do from your end

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways to do this.

First possibility is to override Electron library types declaration in your `typings.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'electron' {
  export interface IpcMain extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
    handle(
      channel: Channel,
      listener: (
        event: IpcMainInvokeEvent,
        ...args: any[]
      ) => Promise<void> | any
    ): void;
  }
}
```

Considering that `Channel` is a string literal (`type Channel = 'channel1' | 'channel2'`), you would get suggestions for `'channel1'` and `'channel2'`, but the initial signature `channel: string` would still be allowed and any string would be accepted.

The second possibility I see is to wrap it, which would give better type safety:

```
const myHandler = (
  channel: Channel,
  listener: (
    event: IpcMainInvokeEvent,
    ...args: any[]
  ) => Promise<void> | any
) => ipcMain.handle(channel, listener);

// only 'channel1' and 'channel2' would be accepted
myHandler('channel1', (event) => {});
```

I you would like to type the arguments currently declared with the spread operator `...args: any[]` you would need to declare the parameters explicitly in both cases:

```
...
listener: (
  event: IpcMainInvokeEvent,
  arg1: string[],
  arg2: boolean,
  arg3: number
) => Promise<void> | any
...
```

Comment: Is this code actually allows to type: 1. Channel 2. Passed arguments 3. Return result in one place for both functions `invoke` and `handle`?

Comment: the `ipcMain.handler` will receive the communication from the `ipcRenderer.invoke`, and the args passed when invoking will be in the handler's listener callback. It's possible to type them the same way the channel was typed `Channel` instead of `string`

Comment: Could you add a more concrete example?

Comment: I added what I have in mind, not sure if this will help